# Integrability on an interval

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that a function f(t) is integrable on [a,b]. Show that there exists some x in [a,b] such that the integral from a to x of f(t)dt = the integral from x to b of f(t)dt.

Does this statement hold if x is in (a,b) instead?

I know this statement holds if a=x=b, so I broke it down into two other cases. In the first case, x is in [a,b), and in the second case, x is in (a,b]. I think I need to use the intermediate value theorem for integrals but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807798/proof-that-int-ax-int-xb/1807816#1807816

Comment: Thanks @MathematicsStudent1122 I found the proof of the first part. Do you know if this still holds if x is in (a,b) instead of [a,b]

Comment: I think a modification of my answer to the linked question would potentially work. Off the top of my head, though, not sure, tbh